# PHP - updating multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Using foreach loops in PHP I would like to add ids to the following object...

$array_before

```
Array
(
    [1111] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name A
            [Subcats] => Array
                (
                    [11111] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Name A.1
                        )
                    [11112] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Name A.2
                        )
                )
        )
    [2222] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name B
            [Subcats] => Array
                (
                    [22221] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Name B.1
                        )
                    [22222] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Name B.2
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

... so it looks similar to the below:

$array_after

```
Array
(
    [1111] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => Name A
            [Subcats] => Array
                (
                    [11111] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 1
                            [Name] => Name A.1
                        )
                    [11112] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 2                       
                            [Name] => Name A.2
                        )
                    [11113] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 3                       
                            [Name] => Name A.2
                        )                       
                )
        )
    [2222] => Array
        (
                    [Id] => 2
                    [Name] => Name B
            [Subcats] => Array
                (
                    [22221] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 1                       
                            [Name] => Name B.1
                        )
                    [22222] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 2                       
                            [Name] => Name B.2
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
LG

Comment: Is this just a sample, or are the an infinite number of (possible) depth levels?

Comment: the expectation is to be able to handle n numbers of depth levels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$id = 0;
array_walk($array,function(&$a) use (&$id) {$a['id'] = ++$id;});
```

This will modify the originl array to add the IDs, rather than create a new one.

Comment: + with the note this requires PHP >= 5.3.

Comment: Works as expected, thank you - I just had to call it on each depth level. 
Once again, thank you.

Comment: If you have multiple depth levels, try [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array-walk-recursive) - you just need to add a bit more to the function to make sure you're at the right level.